# How to add print scale by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, scale

I want to set the print scale to 62%.

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

}
```

```css
@media print {
  #printMe {
    zoom: 62%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> do not print this </h1>

<div id='printMe'>
  Print this only
</div>

<button onclick="printDiv('printMe')">Print only the above div</button>
```

Please help me to set the print scale of the HTML page. I have tried a lot but failed.

Comment: Did you try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale (as recommended by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)? I do suspect though that this is a user-controlled browser setting that you can't really affect - your code cannot change anything within the print dialog box

Comment: P.S. This is absolutely nothing to do with PHP, I have removed the tag.